# Compare params array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I'm working on a method that compares a collection of objects (since the object supports all types), if they are all the same, it returns true, but if one or more differs, it returns false.

This is what I have:

```
    public static bool Compare(bool compareTypes = false, params object[] values)
    {
        if (!compareTypes)
        {
            if (values is null || values.Length == 0) return false;
            else if (values.Length == 1) return true;
            else return values[0] == values[1];
        }
        else
        {
            if (values is null || values.Length == 0) return false;
            else if (values.Length == 1) return true;
            else return values[0].GetType() == values[1].GetType();
        }
    }
```

And it works fine as long as the number of objects is 2.

My problem is that I want the method to compare the value or the type of all parameters that are passed regardless of the amount

> This is what I want my method to do

```
Compare (false, "Hello", "Hello") //True
Compare(false, "Hello", "Bye") //False
Compare(true, 0, 1) //True
Compare(true, "Hi", 20) //False
Compare(false, "LOL", "LOL", "LOL", "LOL") //True
Compare(false, "LOL", "LOL", "LOL", "lol") //False
```

Comment: I think there is place to improve the design of what you are working on..What is the bigger scope of what you are doing? Why passing all items this way in an `object[]` is what you decided to do..

Comment: @GiladGreen I am glad to hear

Comment: You could make your life easier by creating 2 methods: `CompareValue` and `CompareType` instead of doing this `if else` logic splitting inside one method

Comment: using linq, you could use `values.Count() == values.Distinct().Count();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with the logic that works for 2 objects why not just compare all objects in a same way with a loop?

```
public static bool Compare(bool compareTypes = false, params object[] values)
{
    if (!compareTypes)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (values.Length == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (values.Length == 2){
            return values[0] == values[1];
        }
        else 
        {
            bool result = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < values.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if(values[i] != values[i+1])
                {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (values.Length == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (values.Length == 2)
        {
            return values[0].GetType() == values[1].GetType();
        }
        else 
        {
            bool result = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < values.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if(values[i].GetType() != values[i+1].GetType())
                {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a running example with your test cases : https://dotnetfiddle.net/uDA5Mb

Comment: Your code is full of errors as not all paths return a non-existent value and properties

Comment: I sense an IDE warning in that comment - they are not perfect. All paths in this code return a boolean value. The code is just your logic for 2 objects applied to an array of objects

Comment: Well, after some modifications, your code works as expected

Comment: There were some spelling mistakes that I fixed. I also added a runnable example, please take look here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uDA5Mb

Answer (score 0):

You can also use recursive and simplify your code with that way.

```
    public static bool Compare(bool compareTypes = false, params object[] values)
    {
        if (values is null || values.Length == 0)
            return false;
        else if (values.Length == 1)
            return true;
        else if (values.Lenght == 2)
            if (!compareTypes)
                return values[0] == values[1];
            else
                return values[0].GetType() == values[1].GetType();
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < values.Lenght - 1; i++)
               if(!Compare(compareTypes, values[i], values[i+1]))
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Very simple.